# Adding a line in a scatter plot using R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

```
plot(c.6,d.6, xlab="A55 ", ylab="A41", main="H3",cex.main=1)
abline(lm(d.6 ~ c.6),col="red")
```

This code works fine, but I want to add two more lines:  one where y=x+2 and x=y+2

I would like to add these two lines to visualize those values that fall outside of the lines.

Comment: We don't need to see your plot, we need `c.6` and `d.6`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `abline` function:

```
abline(2, 1)
abline(-2, 1)
```

See `?abline`:

> abline(a = NULL, b = NULL, h = NULL, v = NULL, reg = NULL,
>          coef = NULL, untf = FALSE, ...)
>
> Arguments:
>
> a, b  - the intercept and slope, single values.

So, for a specific regression, you could use something like this:

```
abline(
 coef(lm(d.6 ~ c.6))[1] + 2,
 coef(lm(d.6 ~ c.6))[2]
 )
abline(
 coef(lm(d.6 ~ c.6))[1] - 2,
 coef(lm(d.6 ~ c.6))[2]
 )
```